# The return of my inner func callback isn't waited

Tags: c#, func

I don't really know how to name the question so, you're welcome to edit it.

This is my function :

```
public static KeyValuePair<bool, string> IsAuthenticated(Token token)
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> parameters = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        parameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("token", token.ToString()));
        parameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("creation_date", token.Creation_date));

        //MESSAGE
        if (!Plugin.Connectivity.CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
            return (new KeyValuePair<bool, string>(false, "No connectivity."));

        else
        {
            HttpHandler.Post(HttpHandler.ApiAddresses.ISAUTHENTICATED, parameters, (object response, bool isOk) =>
            {
                if (isOk)
                {
                    return (new KeyValuePair<bool, string>(isOk, ""));
                }
                else
                {
                    return (new KeyValuePair<bool, string>(isOk, (response as Exception).Message));
                }
            });
        }

        return (new KeyValuePair<bool, string>(false, "isAuthenticated() didn't worked.."));
    }
```

So, basically, I would like to avoid the last return, but if I do, then I have a warning -> `All code path doesn't return a value` blablabla

But my real problem is that, I would like my delegate func (or whatever you call it) to return the final value.

This is the HttpHandle.Post() function :

```
public static async void Post(string url, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> parameters, Func<object, bool, KeyValuePair<bool, string>> callback)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);
            callback(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() as object, true);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            callback(e as object, false);
        }
    }
```

Because each time, I only reach the **"isAuthenticated() didn't worked.."** return.. Maybe I don't understand something or I'm just totally wrong, please explain to me..

Thank for any help !

Comment: Are you allowed to modify the Post() method? It sounds like you want it to block until the response is received so why make it async in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `Post` should return a `Task<KeyValuePair<...>>` rather than `void`. Then you can either make `IsAuthenticated` `async` as well and `await` the results from `Post` (which should just be returning whatever `callback` returns) or you *may* be able to get away with calling `Result` or `Wait` on it but be aware that this is a frequent source of deadlocks - it's better, if possible, to push `async` all the way up the call stack.

So, `Post` would be:

```
public static async Task<KeyValuePair<bool, string>> Post(string url, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> parameters, Func<object, bool, KeyValuePair<bool, string>> callback)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);
            return callback(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() as object, true);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return callback(e as object, false);
        }
    }
```

The problem with `async void` is that *it will complete its work at some future point in time* and *it doesn't give you any means of tracking that and knowing when it has been done*. That's why it's usually best avoided outside of event handlers.

Comment: Interesting, I had to change some code but, it works, thank you :)